# Change the text of a textarea, from the selected item in a select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that successfully populates a textarea with text from a select, when the select is changed.

```
function Favourites()
{
  $('select#favourites').change(function() {
    var text = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-post');
    $('textarea#post').text(text);
  });
}
```

Problem is if I change the select, delete the contents of the textarea, and change the select again, it no longer populates the textarea.

Any idea why please?

Comment: Why are your selectors `select#fabourites` and `textarea#post`? The # signifies selecting a unique id and therefore you wouldn't need the `select` or `textarea` preceding the id. Also it might help to see the html of the select and textarea elements you're talking about.

Comment: @sgarrett: in this case, the html is irrelevant, because he is using the wrong method to set the value.  See my answer below.

Comment: @sgarrett it can help improve readability if you know what the id is on

Comment: @JeffB .val() is the correct fix, but OP should know about the selectors and their use. See [ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). It makes no sense to have text before the #.

Comment: @Ascherer if you're trying to improve readability come up with a better id. Putting text before # would most likely confuse someone else who would need to make changes to the code.

Comment: @sgarrett: Yep, I wasn't contradicting that point.

Comment: @sgarrett idk about you, but i now know, the #favourites element is a select field, and the #post element is a textarea... kinda helpful if i didnt see the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.val()` instead of `.text()`:

```
 $('#post').val(text);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/HaZWC/

`.text()` essentially sets the text between the tags `<textarea></textarea>`, which sets the default value of the `textarea`.  This is fine as long as the user has not typed anything in the text box.  But, just like when you do `<textarea>My Text</textarea>` in html, the default value is always overridden by what the user inputs.  Because this is an input, the `.val()` function sets the actual value of the input, which overrides the default value.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason that the change function is inside the `Favourites` function? You simply need it in your DOM ready function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('select#favourites').change(function() {
        var text = $('option:selected', this).attr('data-post');
        $('textarea#post').val(text);
    });

});
```

I've also changed:

- the `.text` to `.val` which will always change a form field value correctly
- removed `find` and replaced with method for searching inside `this`: `$('option:selected', this)`

Here's a jsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/sp5L4/2/

Comment: I call the Favourites function from my DOM ready function, it helps keep things organised.

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like `on()` (the new `live()`), also, use `val()` and not `text()`. might be able to use `data()` too

```
$(document).on('change', 'select#favourites', function() {
    var text  = $(this).find('option:selected').data('post');
    $('textarea#post').val(text);
});
```

Comment: ha, ok, depends on the browser i guess?

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'on' method to attach/listen to event handlers throughout the DOM.

```
$('select#favourites').on('change', function(){
  var text = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-post');
  $('textarea#post').text(text);
});
```